# Geth light keeps showing "Looking for peers"

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, peers, import

My Geth server in light mode was running without any issue up to yesterday. But after that, I only receive these messages continuously!

```
INFO [04-19|12:59:22.181] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=9  static=29
INFO [04-19|12:59:35.670] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=29
INFO [04-19|12:59:46.432] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=17 static=29
INFO [04-19|12:59:57.181] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=9  static=29
INFO [04-19|13:00:10.671] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=29
INFO [04-19|13:00:21.408] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=17 static=29
INFO [04-19|13:00:32.182] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=9  static=29
INFO [04-19|13:00:45.671] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=29
INFO [04-19|13:00:56.416] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=17 static=29
INFO [04-19|13:01:07.182] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=9  static=29
INFO [04-19|13:01:20.672] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3  static=29
```

And this does not finish!

May you help me to solve this issue please?

Comment: Are you behind a NAT (router)? Do you port forward? What system do you run this on (Windows / Linux / Mac)? How do you start the geth client?

Comment: I'm using a Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04). This was my initial code:  `geth --syncmode light --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi personal,eth,web3,txpool`

Comment: Are you behind a NAT (router)?

Comment: @Daniel, No I am not

Comment: Super late here, but does the `tried=n` reflect that those peers refused to serve you as a light client?
"This is currently an open issue within the Ethereum community - how do we incentivize people to run full nodes which serve light clients?" https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/run-light-node-geth/

Answer (score 3):

It's Geth's peer discovery mechanism. You can use `--nodiscover` to disable it, which prevents your node from finding peers to connect, but it doesn't prevent other node in the network to connect to your node.